# Adding custom fields to sales_flat_order

Tags: magento-1.7, sales

I've been doing a fair amount of googling, trial and error but I cannot find a solution to the problem.

1. The ability to change the fields and order of sales_order_grid; and
2. The ability to display two custom fields on this grid (filterable).

The former (point 1) has been solved, by extending the `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid` in my custom module (I know about observers, yet other installed modules were overriding my changes with their observers).

Regardless, the latter is my current problem, below are the two methods that have failed me so far.

## Method 1

```
<?php
/*  @var $this Mage_Sales_Model_Mysql4_Setup  */
$this->startSetup();
$connection = $this->getConnection();

/**
 * Create the payment method dropdown field, because this field _may_ be
 * used for searching we will create an index for it.
 */
$connection->addColumn(
    $this->getTable('sales/order_grid'),
    'x_payment_method',
    "ENUM('PayPal', 'SagePay') DEFAULT NULL"
);
$connection->addKey($this->getTable('sales/order_grid'), 'x_payment_type', 'x_payment_type');

/**
 * Create the order channel field to identify where the order was originally
 * generated from. Also add an index for this field for additional filtering.
 */
$connection->addColumn(
    $this->getTable('sales/order_grid'),
    'x_sale_channel',
    "ENUM('Amazon', 'Play', 'eBay', 'Website') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'Website'"
);
$connection->addKey($this->getTable('sales/order_grid'), 'x_sale_channel','x_sale_channel');

$this->endSetup();
```

## Method 2

By this point I was tired of reading the same 7 articles that didn't help, so I tried to get ONE field working; I also checked the error logs in Magento and found "$this->getTable()" was errornous, thus I removed it.

```
<?php
/*  @var $this Mage_Sales_Model_Mysql4_Setup  */
$this->startSetup();
$connection = $this->getConnection();

/**
 * Create the payment method dropdown field, because this field _may_ be
 * used for searching we will create an index for it.
 */
$this->addAttribute('sales_flat_order', 'x_test_option', array(
    'label' => 'X Test Option',
    'type' => 'varchar',
    'input' => 'select',
    'visible' => true,
    'required' => false,
    'position' => 1,
    'visible_on_front'  => false,
    'option' => array('value' => array('web', 'test 1', 'test 2')),
    'default' => array('web'),
));

$this->endSetup();
```

Which makes one beg the question, what is the difference between a column and an attribute? My initial presumption was that, a column is added to an existing core table while an attribute is added to the EAV_* tables and appropriately related.

Comment: Even though that table is flat, the resource model for it is EAV, hence the attribute has to be registered in the EAV config to be written to. Several sales entities *used to* be EAV but were flattened out for performance reasons.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your presumption is correct.
But for the `sales_` table they are one and the same.
Initially the sales entities were EAV. They changed into flat tables starting with version 1.4.0.1 (I think). And for backwards compatibility both methods were kept.
For any other flat tabled entities (cms pages, blocks, polls) you cannot use `addAttribute`, only `addColumn`, but for sales it works both ways.
If you plan to make an extension that has to be compatible with versions before 1.4 then use `addAttribute`, otherwise I see no point in it.

Comment: Thanks for the info I find this really helpful.  Actually, now thinking about it, I suppose the right way is to use `addColumn` method?  Whilst also not using 'getTable' as the sales_flat_order is just that.  I will try that out shortly, and return with a virdict :)

Comment: It turns out I had two problems (one I overlooked); One was `$this->getTable('sales/flat_order')` may as well be set to `sales_flat_order`; the second was `$connection->addKey($this->getTable('sales/order_grid'), 'x_payment_type', 'x_payment_type');`; `x_payment_type` should have been `x_payment_method`.