# addAttribute() vs addColumn()?

Tags: attributes, model, resource-model, entities

While I am aware of the [similar question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/10706/addcolumn-or-addattribute-what-is-the-best-for-performance-migration-us). My question is more generic, that what would happen to both calls whether I actually create a database column or not.

**EDIT**

I know `addColumn()` will add a real table column, but when I'm diving into some core modules, some of them are calling both `addColumn()` and `addAttribute()` to the same field.

What is the difference between them?

**EDIT 2**

Because `addAttribute()` looks very much EAV related to me, after some research I also find some similar names like `addAttributeSet()` and `addAttributeSetNames()`.

How are they differ to each other?

Comment: Thanks for linking to the other question. Based on your edit, I'm inclined to mark this as a duplicate question given that [Marius's answer](http://magento.stackexchange.com/a/17024/5) to the linked question seems to answer your query as well. Will you please check?

Comment: There is still one element that is not clear in my mind, I will add that into my question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's take it step by step.

- `addColumn` adds a column to a table.
- `addAttribute` adds a new attribute for EAV entities. So a new record will be created in the `eav_attribute` table.
- The exception: For the sales module, `addColumn` and `addAttribute` do the same thing. They add a column to a table. The reason is backwards compatibility. Before version 1.4, the sales entities (orders, invoices, shipments, items, ...) were EAV so you had to use `addAttribute`. Starting with 1.4 the sales entities are flat so you have to use `addColumn`. But for backwards compatibility, starting version 1.4, `addAttribute` is just a wrapper for `addColumn`.
- `addAttributeSet` is used for EAV entities and it does what it says. It creates a new attribute set for that entity. I think it is used for products only, because all the other EAV entities (category, customer, customer_address) use a single attribute set.
- `addAttributeSetNames` - I didn't find any occurrence of this anywhere in the core code.