# How to add Custom fields to sales_flat_order in magento

Tags: magento-1.8, orders, database

I am new to magento, If I want to add custom fields to `sales_flat_order` table how Can I do?

`sales_flat_order`

`sales_flat_order_address`

`sales_flat_order_grid`

`sales_flat_order_item`

`sales_flat_order_payment`

`sales_flat_order_status_history`

there are 6 tables are link up one to another. So if I want to add custom field/column to `sales_flat_order` table.

Is there required to add another 5 tables to reference field/column? please guide me in-detail?

guide/suggest me what is the relation between those 6 tables how it forms together at the run time when `saving/updating/deleting/reading` orders.

Thanks.

Comment: Hello need to add field in sales_flat_order and sales_flat_order_grid

Comment: check the links ..http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/5521/add-new-column-to-sales-flat-order-grid,http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13032932/magento-how-to-add-new-attribute-to-sales-order-model

Comment: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/9751/adding-custom-fields-to-sales-flat-order

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to add columns to all the tables.
If you need it in the `sales_flat_order` add it there.
If you need to view the column value in the orders grid then you should add it for the table `sales_flat_order_grid`. If this is the case [see a nice explanation](http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/how-to-extend-magento-order-grid/) on how you can continue with the new column in the grid