# Add an attribute to Orders and Invoices alongside SKU

Tags: magento-1.9, orders, product-attribute, invoice

I would like to add an attribute "Product Code" to show alongside SKU on my orders and invoices. How can I achieve this? The extensions I find seem to be centered around changing your checkout, which I don't want to touch. And any other explanations of this seem very complicated. Is there a solution for my problem? Thanks in advance

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The best way to accomplish this would be to add a field to the sales_flat_order table ([Adding custom fields to sales_flat_order](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/9751/adding-custom-fields-to-sales-flat-order)) (so your order data wont change as product change overtime). Then using a observer you store this info to the file your created.

To add the fields to your email, go to system transactional email then edit/import those template.

Then add the following code where you want it to show.

```
{{var order.field_name_here}}
```

To add these field to your pdf see [Add custom attribute to Magento’s PDF invoice](http://inchoo.net/magento/how-to-add-custom-attribute-to-magentos-pdf-invoice/)