# I want to create column in sales_order table and view custom field on order edit section in magento 2.3.5

Tags: module, event-observer, model, plugin, magento2.3.5-p1

I am added one custom field in checkout address form and i want to store that field data in Database and also display this field in admin order edit page in magento 2.3.5, so anyone can have idea please help me.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: follow this blog https://www.mageplaza.com/devdocs/add-new-fields-address-form-magento-2.html

Comment: thank you but i am also want to add this custom field data should be saved in sales_order table

Comment: Once you will add field like above you will get data in order object and can call in sales order edit page

Comment: Thank you for your reply

Comment: i want to set this kind of mechanisum when i want to add some in my custom field that will be going to store in database's sales order table that thing i want to do.

Comment: i am already added one custom column with name custom_field in database

Comment: Can you tell me the exact purpose of your adding field ?in checkout address and order efit page ?

Comment: My main purpose is to  when customer wants to checkout at that time he/she can write whatever id should be displayed to admin sales order edit page in a edit field.

Comment: I hope you can understand that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow this blog https://www.mageplaza.com/devdocs/add-new-fields-address-form-magento-2.html

And you will have order object so you can add in your edit page as well ..Let me know if you want more help

Can you check following link to add attribute in order field ?

[Adding custom fields to sales_flat_order](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/9751/adding-custom-fields-to-sales-flat-order)

Comment: yes your answer is right and helpful but i am doing this thing already and now i want to do this thing:- "i want to set this kind of mechanisum when i want to add something in my custom field that will be going to store in database's sales order table that thing i want to do"

Comment: @DeepShah Check my answer I edited

Comment: hello, but i want to display dyunamic ids on sales order edit page in that admin can also see the order id and change the order id and that id should be updated in sales order table in custom_field column. I hope you got my idea -@ParulThakkar

Comment: original order id or any custom order if that can be edited ?

Comment: custom order id